# Using Facebook Single Sign On (or other features) without the official Facebook app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-login

I would like to integrate Facebook into an application - enable login using Facebook credentials (Single Sign On, to login to a third-party service), and also share some wall posts.

The problem is, I don't want to depend on the installation of the official Facebook app. 
I heard about some solution involving opening Facebook login from a WebView, but didn't find details.

Anyone has experience with that?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do it using the OAuth for getting permission, then use the Graph API to post on users walls.

Please see this link for OAuth: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

And this link for Graph API documentation:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

especially for posting http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

Comment: After more research, this is the correct answer. The official SDK falls back automatically to OAuth if the Facebook app doesn't exist.

Comment: @SirKnigget: "falls back automatically to OAuth" --- uhm, what? OAuth is an authorization protocol used to interact with FB API, with either an application or without one.

Comment: Right, so if the Facebook application is not installed, the SDK does an OAuth authorization using a WebView.

Answer (score 0):

All Facebook APIs built on the idea that you perform request from a particular application (identified by application id). So the answer is *NO*, you cannot perform API queries (as well as authentication) without having registered an app.

Comment: I don't mind registering my own app, all I want is to be able to do the same thing without requiring the official Facebook app to be installed on the device.